# ShowDialog exiting on certain events

Tags: c#

I have a main form, but once I show the main form, I use ShowDialog to pop up my login form, and I hide the main form. Once the user logs in, I just close the login form and everything works fine, the main form shows up.

However.. when I exit the login form, it still shows the main form, because, obviously, it's a dialog. How can I prevent the user from reaching the main form when they exit the login form?

Thanks.

Comment: hackish: dont allow closing the dialog, sane: retrieve the result of the dialog - if its not "valid" exit application?

Comment: use `Application.Exit()' on close event of `login` form or on the event of `Cancel` button or some other

Comment: Just do these things in the proper order.  Edit your Main() method in Program.cs and put the ShowDialog() call *before* the Application.Run() call.

Answer (score 2):

I see such options:

- don't allow exiting the login dialog (unless together with closing along the whole application)
- if user exists the login dialog disable the whole main form (set Enabled = false on it's crucial controls and the whole form). Probably except the main menu when you can exit the application or invoke the login dialog again

Comment: And what would be the message in the first case? "Please, dear sir, login or reboot your PC"? ^^

Comment: What message? I don't understand the downvote. User can login or simply close the application.

Comment: the message displayed in the dialog. User can not "simply close the application", because modal dialog prevents him accessing the main window.

Comment: That's why by "don't allow exiting the login dialog" I meant that it shouldn't be possible to exit the dialog only, without closing the application. This a typical UI schema used in many applications. I've edited the answer again, hope now it doesn't leave room for so much interpretation ;)

Answer (score 1):

Use the result of the ShowDialog() to determine if the user has logged in or not. If not, just close the application, otherwise continue the application.

Another but less nice solution: set a Main-form property in your login-form and set it when you open the login form. In the closing event of the login-form you can also close the main form.

```
//the property in the login-form
public YourMainForm MainForm{ get; set; }

//setting the property from the main-form
var login = new LoginForm();
login.MainForm= this;

//closing of the mainform
MainForm.Close();
```

Comment: I used your solution, however, how can I refer to the main form so I can close it? I tried using the property, but it gives me errors.

Comment: I edited the code a bit (corrected few mistakes). What's not working?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to hide the form. just add the controls to a panel and make it invisible.

```
panel1.visible=false;
```